# Horizontal padding with vertical scrollbar but no horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

How can you add horizontal padding to an inline-block div that has a vertical scrollbar (like a sidebar) without getting a horizontal scrollbar? I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require a fixed width (just uses the width of the content of the sidebar).

I tried putting the padding in the inner div and the scrollbar on the outer div, thinking it would then make room for both, but the scrollbar still steps on the right padding.

Example:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='div2'>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/msxjL52d/2/

Answer (score 0):

Was this what you were looking for?  I added width: 100%; to #div1.  You should also be able to use width:auto; if you don't want it 100%.

Note: based on comment below #div1 was changed to have width: auto; padding-right: 1em;

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right:0 ; overflow: hidden; }
#div1 { display: inline-block; height: 100%; width: auto; padding-right: 1em; overflow-y: auto; background-color: gray;}
#div2 { display: inline-block; padding: 0 10px; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='div2'>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need the sidebar to stay shrink-wrapped to the width of the text inside it. Making it 100% width doesn't work in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: try the above.  I changed it to...

width: auto; padding-right: 1em;

Answer (score 0):

If someone can provide a less hacky answer, please do.

The following works, at least in Firefox: add about 16px to the `padding-right` for the width of the scrollbar, and set `overflow-x` to `hidden`.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 26px 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'>
  <div id='div2'>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
    text<br>
  </div>
</div>
```